# Can any one explain why does a single threaded program in .net (VS) spawn so many other threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I work on a multi-threaded application. And while debugging i have seen many instances where apart form the main thread and the threads my program creates, a lot more worker threads are created automatically. 
So i made a small program below with just main class and some few classes that just has a simple function to print out class name.
I debug this and there is the same behavior. For a simple program the thread window shows a lot of threads have been spawned.

I read that some threads may be created for garbage collection and that same thread may run in different cores after context switching but i still can't figure out why so many other worker threads are created that neither has no name or code block associated with it.

Can anyone put some insight into this.

[image: Simple Program Spawning multiple threads]

Comment: Some of these are debugger threads, for example the vshost thing. Run this in Release mode without debugger attached, then attach it later. Make the first line of main Debugger.Break();

Comment: Thanks @rene Wonder how google search missed that!